White lines on my mesh when Cavity is on
I'm having trouble figuring out why I keep getting these white lines when I turn on my Cavity. I tried playing around with the Cavity setting, but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. 

Those lines come from the Type > World, from the Ridge settings in the World Space to be precise. The higher the value, the more visible the lines are. So they appear if you use World or Both.
To get rid of them you either need to decrease the Distance in the additional options (accessible through the gear icon on the right), but I mean really really low like 0.001 - which means the cavity type World is almost disabled and you can just as good only keep it at Screen.
Or you can increase the Distance value until the lines disappear, then it depends on what value is still giving some effect where you want it or otherwise it basically comes down to the same like before, you could just as well disable it completely.
Or you have to make the object much smoother with a higher mesh resolution, like adding a Subdivision Surface modifier or if you already have one, increase the Level value.


+1  Yeah, FWIW I just keep World turned off entirely.
